# Burn metadata onto a picture

Tags: editing, software-recommendation, metadata, photos, jpeg

I have a lot of JPEG photos taken by GoPro. All the photos have metadata on them, but I want that metadata to be displayed on the picture. I can view metadata in the properties of photo, but I want to see it in the photo as well.
Please guide me if there is any way to do this.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you will consider to use viewer which will display the image meta info w/o changing the original photos?